# Relevance of a PhD with a quantitative psychology group for applied math

Tags: phd, mathematics, changing-fields

My background is in mathematics, with a main interest in mathematical statistics / biostatistics, and I am considering applying for a PhD position with a quantitative psychology group. The research itself can apparently be made statistically challenging towards the candidate's interests, which sounds appealing. I am not sure if I want to continue in academia after the PhD, but it would preferably be in mathematical statistics or biostatistics.

Would a PhD research with a quantitative psychology group take away this option or make it more difficult, even if the reseach itself is approached from a mathematical statistics view?

Comment: This might be a better fit at cogsci.se since it seems like you are asking about the overlap of two fields.

Comment: @StrongBad Wouldn't math.se be better in that case, since I am wondering about the prospects in the field of math after such a research?

Comment: Take a good look at the publications that have come out of this group.